Retrieve Collections Associated with a Specific Product Using Shopify Storefront API
I’m working on a Shopify project and need to find all the collections associated with a specific product using its Product ID. For example, if "Red T-shirt" is a product that belongs to multiple collections, I want to retrieve the list of those collections.
Is it possible to achieve this using the Shopify Storefront API? If yes, which query or endpoint should I use? Are there any specific parameters or best practices for this use case?
Any help or sample code would be greatly appreciated.

In this link, you can easily find the topic Retrieve a list of all smart collections for a certain product_id
# Session is activated via Authentication
test_session = ShopifyAPI::Context.active_session

ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.all(
  session: test_session,
  product_id: "632910392",
)


With the SFAPI, use a query like this:
query GetProduct($id: ID!) {
  product(id: $id) {
    collections(first: 250) {
      nodes {
        title
        description
        # ...more data as needed
      }
    }
  }
}

And the variable:
{
  "id": "gid://shopify/Product/123"
}

On the admin panel, you can install the GraphiQL app to test both Storefront and Admin api: https://shopify.dev/docs/storefronts/headless/building-with-the-storefront-api/api-exploration/graphiql-storefront-api
